# Python breakpoint() without console

Tags: python, pyinstaller, breakpoints

I often use the python breakpoint() command as a way of debugging code or for changing the values of variable on-the-fly. This works great when I launch a python script from the (windows) console, as breakpoint() lets me type commands in that console.

My question is how do I do achieve something similar when running a python script launched some other way? For example, when I package my code into an .exe with PyInstaller (with the no-console option to keep it tidy) and launch the .exe, breakpoint() does nothing at all. I know one way to remove this problem is to compile the .exe without the no-console option, but I'd rather have it there as it just keeps everything clean. A similar problem also arises when running a python script via a os.execl() call in another.

Is there someway of making the code launch its own console whenever breakpoint() is called, and having that console control the debugging commands? I suspect that this is possible through manipulating the PYTHONBREAKPOINT variable, but I don't know how, or where to start looking.

Comment: you can always open manually console/terminal/cmd.exe and run .exe in console.

Comment: @furas thanks for the idea, I tried and it doesn't work. The console runs the .exe in a single line and then returns the prompt rather than keeping it open (or whatever the correct word is) while its running. It's also not a practical workaround for when a script is called by os.exec().

Comment: You seem to want things both ways. You want to have no console, but also have a console. That's probably not possible. I'm also not sure you should really be using a debugging feature like `breakpoint()` for a deployed script.

Comment: That's why I was asking if I could launch a console when breakpoint() is called. I know what I'm doing is slightly orthodox, but I was using it as a simple way to implement a "cheat menu" kind of thing, where advanced users can change variable values live.

And the problem is also present even when there is a console, but the script is launched via an ```os.exec``` call from another script